# How to install cuda-toolkit-10-0 on ubuntu 18.1?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvidia

I've installed Nvidia 415, and Result of command :- `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version.`

NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  415.13  Wed Oct 31 19:07:36 CDT 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1)

Result of command `sudo apt-cache policy cuda-toolkit-10-0.`

cuda-toolkit-10-0:

Installed: (none)

Candidate: (none)

Version table:

```
 10.0.130-1 -1

    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But when I try to install using `sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-10-0`,
i get error

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package cuda-toolkit-10-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cuda-toolkit-10-0' has no installation candidate

Comment: CUDA 10.0 officially supports Ubuntu 18.04 but not Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score -1):

To install any version of cuda and nvcc follow steps on nvidia [docs](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_network)

For ubuntu 20.04 and cuda 11.6:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

For ubuntu 18.04 and cuda 10.0:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda=10.0
```

**IMPORTANT**:

To have default behavior (as with installation with 1
`sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`) `create symlink`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/<your-cuda-version>/bin/nvcc /usr/bin/nvcc
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-11.6/bin/nvcc /usr/bin/nvcc 
or 
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/nvcc /usr/bin/nvcc
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question "How to install CUDA 10.0 on Ubuntu 18.1"?

Comment: @talonmies
I have written this as generic, just change the version to the one you want....